# Session variable is always null in SessionTimeOut Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, attributes

I'm working on a MVC 5 application.
Below is my code in web.config for session.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="AutoDetect" timeout="1" />   

<pages enableSessionState="true">
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Routing"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

When a user logs in to the application, I'm storing his username in session.

I have the following code for SessionTimeOutAttribute to check if session is null, but `HttpContext.Current.Session["userName"]` is always null and ending up in login page in a loop.

```cs
public class SessionTimeOutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["userName"] ==null)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Session/Create");
                return;
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

**Update:**
I'm using `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on login action method.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(UserModel user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid){....}
```

If login is successful i'm saving username in session `Session["userName"] = userAccount.Username;`

This is how i'm using the attribute on controllers

```
[Authorize]
[SessionTimeOut]
public class TestController : Controller
{
```

Comment: How are you authenticating the user. I means forms Authentication?

Comment: I suggest you to increase the value of the timeout property in web.config to say 20 and check. 1 is too low.

Comment: Yes, I'm using forms authentication to authenticate. I have set the timeout to 20 but still session is null

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all your code, do the following:

- Do *not* put this attribute on your login controller or action.
- In your login action/routine, if successful, set the user name value into session.

If you register this attribute as global or put it at the class level of the controller that has the login action, then this attribute will be applied and give you the endless loop.

I suggest not using attributes that interact with session as globals, as some controllers may not need session state.

Comment: i'm not using this attribute to login controller. i'm setting session values when login is successful. The session attribute suppose to check if session is null/empty and redirect to login page. But, somehow the session is always throwing null even after setting it in login action.

Answer (score 0):

try to change it to below in the web.config

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="AutoDetect" timeout="20" />
```

where timeout is munites of expiry for the session.